# Android Studio Network Profiler not showing response?

Tags: android-studio

I am using android studio 3.4.1. I call some apis from my app. In android studio network profiler it's showing request graph. If select the request it's not showing response. But in postman it's working fine. Also 200 response request is showing in android studio. But others not showing. What's the problem here please help me.

[image: H]

Comment: I'm so sorry, I have never seen that AS has such function, where I can find these views at profiler?

Comment: Are you using HttpUrlConnection or OkHttp directly or indirectly? These are the only two supported by AS. I'm getting this same problem with HttpUrlConnection, though, so I want to know if that your case is the same to not send a duplicate question here in such case.

Comment: JFYI, I have replaced HttpUrlConnection with OkHttp3 in my code and the last, unlike the former, works flawlessly with AS profiler.